# How to get the spectrogram from an audio file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

So i'm trying to map some audio into an image (spectogram) in this way : 
*Get the spectrum data (512 samples). 
*Make an png 512*512 => the value of the pixel on the row i and col j = the amplitude on the frequency j for the sample j ( it take aprox 10 seconds for the image to be created)

[512 samples for the spectrum data => 43 Hz / sample]

but the results are not so good (i uploaded one of those : [image]).

My goal is to feed an Convolutional Neural Network with those images but with my technique i gen an precision of 56% which is not good at all:(

Some advices please?

Comment: Do you use windowing and overlapping to create your spectrogram? Also, 43 Hz per FFT bin is not enough for most applications.

Comment: You are right!
I increased the sample number to 1024, added some buffers and now works perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks rougly like a spectrogram should. One suggestion would be to switch both x (frequency) and amplitude (color) to a logarhitmic scale, it matches our perception much better, but I am not sure if it makes any difference at all for a neural network

Comment: Thanks,
Mapping the row values of the amplitude to a logarhitmic scale + some other small changes made the difference!Now the precision is over 80%